# 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found

Tags: xcode, opencv

I successfully  installed OpenCV on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

After that I configured Xcode 4.5.2 by following this [guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/UsingOpenCVUnderOSX) by  [SSteve](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/SSteve) even that this guide was for Xcode 3.5.1 - everything was like it's suppose to be.

My openCV dylib's are in: /usr/lib

1. Always Search User Paths: YES
2. Framework Search Path: /usr/lib** (** stands for recursive search)
3. Header Search Path: /usr/lib** (** stands for recursive search)

Full error message:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
```

Comment: Did you set up the include dirs? is opencv2/opencv.hpp in the include dir?

Comment: Framework Search Path had to be set to my 3rdparty/ in the project tree. tnx a lot

Comment: care to share which last opencv2 is stable enough for production? tnx

Comment: @AntonTropashko i can't answer that question, because I didn't used opencv2 for a while :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Header Search Path: /usr/lib** (** stands for recursive search)

It's definitely wrong. You should setup this path like:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv2**
```

or:

```
/usr/include/opencv2**
```

From your link:

> In the Search Paths section set Header Search Paths to
>   /usr/local/include (/opt/local/include if you used MacPorts)

Comment: I've solved this problem but other problems persist now, do you want to assist whit them ? :) Example:: '(something)' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @h4cky no, sorry. Try to search in Google: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q='DBL_EPSILON'+was+not+declared+in+this+scope&oq='DBL_EPSILON'+was+not+declared+in+this+scope&aqs=chrome.0.57.371&sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: If you're having more problems, ask more questions. But do try a little research first.

Comment: @ArtemStorozhuk Hi,i am using Xcode 4.6 i got same problem "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found" i set the path what you mentioned, but still showing the same error......help me

Comment: @krish did you found the problem ?

Comment: This no longer works for 2021, and the original guide linked in the question isn't even available any more.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I wrote:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv4
```

Header Search Path. I used opencv4, so I needed to add search_path a little bit deeper