# 'opencv2/core/core_c.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, opencv

I am having the same issue as was reported in 
[question #13953570](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953570/opencv2-opencv-hpp-file-not-found)

Only I am showing something that might help determine the problem and I am new enough to Xcode to not be able to figure this out.

In main.cpp, Xcode is not liking the include statement in the instructions.
    Instead of 
        #include < opencv2/opencv.hpp> 
    it appears to like 
        #include "opencv.hpp"

But then I have another problem on the first include in opencv.hpp.  It's like I'm pointing to far down in the directory structure.  The error is Lexical or Preporcessor Issue 'opencv2/core/core_c.h' file not found.  If you look at my Header Search Paths and Library Search Paths, I haven't gone down to the opencv2 directory.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahaaaa!  I restarted Xcode and found some phantom paths in there.  Also, Always Search User Paths should be Yes.  Problem solved.